# Probability of two tens in a random shuffled deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a standard deck of card with 32 cards (used for [skat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skat_%28card_game%29)) that contains exactly 4 tens. The deck is randomly shuffled and I take the first half.

What is the probability that the half contains exactly two tens?

I worked out the answer to $ \frac{360}{899} \approx. 0.4 $. I'm very unsure about the correctness of the solution or there might be a mucht simpler way to get it than I have. Do you think the answer is correct? Do you know a faster way to get to the answer? Maybe I'm just to new to the field.

I argued the following way:

If I want to get two specific tens (say heart and diamond) in my first half of the deck and not the other two, that it equivalent to picking 16 cards, while two of them must be the two specific tens I want and 14 are not the two other tens.

If I were to pick the two tens I want at the beginning and then only cards I don't want the probability is:
$$ \frac{2}{32} \frac{1}{31} \frac{28}{30} \cdots\frac{15}{17} $$

Since the events of picking up the two tens I want can happen anywhere I think I get
 $$ \binom{16}{2} \frac{2 \times 1 \times 28^{\underline{14}}}{32^{\underline{16}}}  $$
because there are $ \binom{16}{2} $ possibilities to choose the positions were I pick the correct tens. $ x^{\underline{n}} = x (x-1) \cdots (x-(n-1)) $ is supposed to be a [Falling Power](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html).

Now I think there are $ \binom{4}{2} $ ways to pick my specific tens so the overall Probability for having exactly two tens in a random half of my deck would be:
$$ \binom{4}{2} \binom{16}{2} \frac{2 \times 1 \times 28^{\underline{14}}}{32^{\underline{16}}}  $$

Comment: In your first display, the last multiplicitive term should be $15/17$, I think.  Other than that, it seems fine. Your approach is certainly correct.

Comment: David's method is technically correct and simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, though your working can be simplified.

The total number of $16$-card hands that can be chosen from your $32$-card pack is the binomial coefficient $C(32,16)$.  To choose a hand of the kind you want:

(1) choose 2 of 4 tens: this can be done in $C(4,2)$ ways; and

(2) choose 14 of 28 other cards: this can be done in $C(28,14)$ ways.

So the probability is
$$\frac{C(4,2)C(28,14)}{C(32,16)}$$
which simplifies to $\frac{360}{899}$.